# How do I restore missing menu extras (clock, wi-fi, etc)?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

When I log in to Mac OS X (10.10.5) I sometimes find that most of my menu extras are missing (clock, wi-fi, sound, bluetooth, etc.). If I logout and login, they almost always come back, but this takes too much time.

I suspect the problem is caused by [menumeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/) but I find this menulet too useful to uninstall it.

How can I reset my menu extras (aka menulets) without logging out?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my menu extras back without logging out by running `killall SystemUIServer` in the Terminal.app.

I found the answer from zane's [Recover missing menubar icons - revisited System](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060203133729554) post. The post is from 2006, but the trick still works on Yosemite.